# Find the derivative of $y=\cos(x) - 2\sin(x),$ when the gradient is $1$

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives

I need to find the smallest positive value of $x$ for which the gradient of the curve has value 1.

For this equation:

$$
y =\cos(x)-2\sin(x)
$$

The answer is **2.5c grad.**

The following is my working out but I’ve stopped at the factor formula, how can I change the equation having just $\sin()$ functions? Or is there another neat way?

$$
y = \cos(x)-2\sin(x) \\ 
\frac{d}{dx} \cos(x)-2\sin(x) = 1 \\ 
\frac{dy}{dx} =-\sin(x)-2\cos(x) = 1 \\ 
\frac{dy}{dx} =\sin(x)+2\cos(x) = -1 \\  
\frac{dy}{dx} = \sin^2(x)+2\cos(x)\sin(x)=-\sin(x)
$$

Comment: What is the goal of the multiplication by $\sin(x)$ on the last line ?

Comment: I multiplyed both sides by sin(x), to have 2cos(x)sin(x) to work with the factor formula (trig), I though going this way a way to the solution, but I can't find a way out.

Comment: Do you know how to solve the trigonometric equation $a+b\sin(x)+c\cos(x)=0$ ?

Comment: I was trying to get the equation in the form of aY^2+bY+c=0 and substitute Y with sin(x).

Comment: @ Claude Leibovici:  nope, nothing comes in my mind... I'll look at your suggestion.

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Trigonometry/Solving_Trigonometric_Equations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\sin x + 2\cos x + 1 = 0\tag{1}$$  Now use the [Weierstrass substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution) $y = \tan\left(\frac x2\right).$  From this, it follows that $$\sin x = \frac {2y}{y^2 + 1},\;\cos x = \frac{1-y^2}{y^2 + 1}\tag{2}$$

Then, substituting the values from $(2)$ into $(1)$ gives us $$ \frac {2y}{y^2 + 1} + \frac{2(1-y^2)}{y^2 + 1} + 1=0$$

Now, solving for $y$, $$\begin{align} &\quad \frac {2y}{y^2 + 1} + \frac{2(1-y^2)}{y^2 + 1} + 1=0 \\ \\
&\iff \dfrac{2y+2(1-y^2)+ y^2 + 1}{y^2 + 1} = 0\\ \\
&\iff \frac{y^2 - 2y - 3}{y^2 +1} = 0\\ \\
&\iff y^2 - 2y - 3 = (y - 3)(y+1) = 0\\ \\
& \iff y = 3\;\text{ or }\;y = -1
\end{align}$$

Now simply recall that $\;y = \tan\left(\frac x2\right) \implies \tan^{-1}(y) = \frac x2 \iff x = 2\tan^{-1}(y).$

So use $x = 2\tan^{-1}(y)$ to solve for $x$. One of your two $y$ values will yield the desired conclusion.

Comment: A nice application of the transform-solve-backtransform pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: 
$$
\sin x+2 \cos x= \sqrt{5} \sin(x+63.4^{\circ})
$$

Comment: “Dont give a child a fish but show him how to fish” as said  Mao Tse-tung

Comment: The rod seems broken or I misuse it. I did not downvote yet, but I don't get the expected $143.13^\circ$.

Comment: I got $143.13$ !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks. Put $143.13^\circ$ in that identity and it holds. So I made a mistake using it to solve for $x$. I will give it an upvote.